# Inhumans vs. Mutants in the Marvel Universe

Tags: marvel, mutant, inhumans

What's the difference between those two? Aren't Inhumans supposed to be an evolution of the human race "forced" by the Kree? Which is almost the same as Mutants, the natural evolution of the human race...

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: “What exactly am I missing?” The difference between natural and forced evolution?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite IIRC the current theory is that the Celestials "forced" the mutant evolution, so the two are not really as different as it seems.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: oh! Gotcha.

Comment: So the difference would be the origin of the evolution? Kree vs Celestials? That's it? Basically, making the inhumans just a different group of mutants?

Comment: yes, but it's a teensy bit more complex than that. sorry, took a while to look up some specifics for my answer.

Comment: The out of universe difference is that Marvel/Disney don't have the movie rights to mutants but they do for inhumans.

Comment: @numaroth: that would be the out of universe difference if Inhumans were introduced now to get around rights problems. But, AFAIK (precisely: as far as Wikipedia tells ne), Inhumans exist since 1965.

Comment: @Taladris The Inhumans have existed for quite a while, but that's not an issue because Marvel never sold their movie rights away. The reason Marvel doesn't have the movie rights to mutants is because they sold those rights to Fox back in 1994.  Part of the reason Fox keeps making X-men movies is so that the rights don't lapse and go back to Marvel/Disney.

Comment: What you are missing is the original link to both of their origins: the Celestials. The Inhumans were an experiment by the Kree to RECOVER their own metahuman potential by grafting superpowers from other species experimented on by the Celestials. The Inhumans were NOT the first species the Kree experimented on to find this. Mutants are the Celestial experiment to create a form of mutant whose power would allow them to alter reality at the fundamental level. The end product of that experimentation was the mutant genome. Franklin Richards was the desired meta-mutant with reality altering powers.

Comment: While they may look the same, the two groups have fundamentally different ways of expressing their abilities, one is a random expression brought on by a mutagen. Every Inhuman has powers once exposed to the Terregen Mists. The other is an unnatural selection with the X-gene as the expression of their abilities. This happens without any external catalysts, though it can be possible for mutants to have increased abilities under the right circumstances. It is possible to have the genes for mutation but not be a fully developed mutant.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They are, indeed, very similar. The main difference is very technical, based on the "origin" of their non-human genetics, and how those changes are activated.

### The X-Factor

***Mutants*** are humans that possess a genetic variation known as the X-Gene or X-Factor, which (at least in the main continuity) was introduced into the human population by the Celestials. Biologically, they are classified as the sub-species  *Homo sapiens superior*, as opposed to normal humans, *Homo sapiens sapiens*.

Mutant powers activate naturally, either at birth, or more often, at puberty. This is because the X-Gene appears on the 23rd chromosome, the sex chromosome, which mostly affects the production of hormones related to sexuality and puberty.

### Terrigenesis

***The Inhumans*** are humans that descend from a very primitive group of *Homo sapiens sapiens* that was genetically manipulated by the Kree to encode the *potential* for enhanced mutations into their genetic code. Biologically, they are classified as *Homo sapiens inhumanus*.

Inhuman powers would normally remain dormant for their entire lives. They must be exposed to the Terrigen Mists, a process called Terrigenesis, in order for those powers to activate. (In the MCU, for example, there are clear changes in DNA between pre- and post- Terrigenesis Inhumans.)

### Related?

Despite their differences, X-Gene mutants and Terrigenesis mutants are extremely similar. The process by which their powers manifest once triggered is largely the same: the mutation produces new proteins, which in turn trigger changes to other bodily systems, which result in powers.

In particular, during the *Son of M* storyline, most mutants were de-powered: their X-Gene activity was suppressed and their mutant powers went away. However, exposing a former mutant to Terrigenesis restored their powers, which indicates an extremely close link, genetically, between the two subspecies.

### Cross-Breeding

Since all three (human, Inhuman, and mutant) are still the same species, they can freely breed with each other and produce viable, fertile offspring.

As far as their genetic mutation goes, the X-Gene appears to work like any other human gene, while the Inhuman genetic changes appear to be highly dominant, based on the known pairings:

- An X-Mutant and Human produce either X-mutants *or* humans, based on inheritance of the X-Gene. See, for example, Wolverine's 6 children, 2 of which were mutants.
- An X-Human and Inhuman appears to produced an Inhuman; The only example I know of is Quicksilver and Crystal's daughter, Luna, who appeared human until exposed to Terrigen Mists, so it's not clear if such a pairing *could* produce an X-Mutant or not.
- An Inhuman and Human also appears to produce an Inhuman; many of the Inhumans have human parents. (This idea appears in the MCU as well: Quake (Daisy Johnson) has been rewritten as an Inhuman, who's power comes from her mother; her father is still Calvin Zabo, a normal human)

The last bullet is particularly important in the Inhumans story line, because there are *a whole lot* of human/Inhuman hybrids; there are entire groups (e.g. the "Lost Tribes") of Inhumans that intermingled with human populations over the centuries, and their offspring are capable of being activated by Terrigenesis. These are commonly called the "new Inhumans", for example see this list: http://marvel.wikia.com/List_of_New_Inhumans

Comment: NOTE: Inhuman genetic purity is actually a huge part of their storylines; I omitted a ton of that information because I think I was already digressing too much, but they make a big deal out of pure vs. impure Inhumans.

Comment: Aren't the original kree subjects cro-magnens and not homo sapiens?

Comment: @cde cro-magnon *is* *homo sapiens sapiens*, just an old name for the very early emergence of that species. The Celestials did experiment with *homo erectus* (to make the Eternals), but the Kree were engineering changes to *homo sapiens*

Comment: It's worth pointing out that mutants are what humans are naturally evolving into.  At some point in the future all people will naturally be mutants.  That's not the case for Inhumans.

Comment: It's actually not clear if mutants are a result of "natural" evolution; I believe the current story is that the Celestials embedded the "mutant potential" into various early *Homo* genus, and the X-Gene is the manifestation of that. There have been mutants on Earth-616 for at least 5000 years. The Inhumans are the result of the Kree taking what the Celestials did to *homo erectus* and splicing it into *homo sapiens*

Comment: Huhm, there appears to be a 4th/5th possibility missing from your bullet points:  Offspring of non-activated Inhumans.  If they're also Inhumans, instead of human or mutant, then all Inhuman offspring are Inhuman - that's the most likely future of humanity, barring reality-altering powers or genocide

Comment: I was including both activated and unactivated Inhumans together, assuming that their underlying genetics would be passed on either way, but I admit I don't know that that's a fair assumption

Comment: Re: the *Son of M* story; terrigenesis gave depowered mutants powers that were *generally similar* to what they had as mutants, but by no means identical. Quicksilver's TG-based power wasn't super-speed, but a time-travel-based ability (that, in some instances, could sort-of mimic speed powers (I think)).

Comment: Also: New Inhumans' siblings and parents may not be susceptible to terrigenesis; as I recall, Inferno was, his sister wasn't, but her kid was. It seems like it may be a recessive genetic trait (or there would logically be more New Inhumans than there were)

Answer (score 6):

#### The difference is an order of magnitude. The first was meant to develop a presumably powerful event of metahuman development through "natural selection." The second was an attempt to graft the metahuman potential of humanity back to the Kree species performing the experiments.

The primary difference between mutants and Inhumans is causal. The technology which creates the ability to have mutants in the Human population was artificially implanted in Humanity by the Celestials and has been exploited by the Kree allowing the creation of the Inhumans.

The Inhumans are merely a subset of humanity where further genetic experimentation and eugenic breeding, first by the Kree and then later by the Inhumans, has led to the ability to trigger a process of specialized abilities similar to mutant powers artificially using the Terrigen Mists. This process has happened on other worlds where the Kree have experimented, as well. This process was meant to help artificially jumpstart the evolution process again in the Kree species.

### Mutants in the Marvel Universe

- In the Marvel Universe mutant development is a genetic modification made upon the Human genome using an unknown technology by the Celestials. The modification has been made to every human, active mutant or not.
- The mutant property is available to any Human being but may only be made manifest by an unknown aspect of recombination in genetic properties. This means any Human in the Marvel Universe born on Earth during the period where Humanity was recombinated with Celestial mutant markers will bear those markers and is thus capable of producing mutant offspring.
- Having these markers does not guarantee your offspring will have mutant powers however. Nor is it easy for anyone to distinguish the potential for mutant development from two non-mutant parents. Whatever the technology which causes the development of the X-gene and the resulting abilities is still unable to be isolated and distinguished. Mutants only seem to be able to be easily detected once puberty and their mutant abilities are developing.

### Inhumans in the Marvel Universe

- The Inhuman genetics are a modification of the Celestial adaptation to the Human genome, created by the Kree in an attempt to jumpstart their own species formerly active Celestial genetic technology which in the Kree has appeared to have reached its apex. The Kree no longer "evolve" mutant capabilities. Their Celestial technology has been rendered inactive, perhaps indicating the Kree are as evolved as they can be.
- The Kree, in order to restart that Celestial technology engine for mutation began performing experiments all over the galaxy on species where the Celestials made modifications.
- Their experiments yielded an ability to cause specified genetic patterns to be activated (randomly) through a process called Terregenesis. There were eugenic programs where the Kree isolated families whose genetic potential yielded potential mutations. These families were bred and their genomes mapped until the process could be activated artificially using the Terrigen mists.
- Inhuman DNA still resides in many of the Humans on the Marvel Earth and they were not all living within the Great Refuge with the Inhumans. Some Inhumans refused to enter the Great Refuge, others had the ability to leave using their abilities. Once the forcefield which isolated the Inhumans from humanity was destroyed, Inhumans who could pass for Humans found their way into the Human populations further spreading their genetic material.

### See Also:

- [Are the offspring of mutates in the Marvel Universe considered to be mutants?](https://www.quora.com/Marvel-Comics/Are-the-offspring-of-mutates-in-the-Marvel-Universe-considered-to-be-mutants/answer/Thaddeus-Howze)
- [Who are the Inhumans?](https://www.quora.com/Who-are-the-Inhumans/answer/Thaddeus-Howze)

Answer (score 2):

Mutants are natural by gen-x. Inhumans are created, mutated by technology. Practically they are the same, but genetically they are not the same. I don't know how it works, but there must be some facts in Marvel Universe. But for me this is messed up.

But mix of two "not-normal" human kind, maybe can do Xhuman or inhuman, or even human. Because everything is in us, every genes.

Apart from the Marvel Universe, genetics says grandfather genes, possibly even great-grandfather genes can be inherited. Maybe in Marvel this can be too.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've learned the main difference is that Inhumans need Terragen mist to transform while mutants are born with their abilities.

Answer (score -1):

Mutants gain power by natural means, mainly the x-genes. Their powers are often affecting physical body, mental energy, or elemental. Inhumans gain theirs by Terrigen mist and can get any power that has ever been noted. Theirs is also often more powerful.

Comment: Hi, what were you hoping to add beyond the [current accepted answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83243/3804)?